# ACF Custom Widget on Woocommerce Shop Page (Repeater)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, widget, advanced-custom-fields

I have a big issue with an ACF custom widget,  I would like to setup a Repeater style using ACF Pro displayed in the Sidebar on the Shop page of WooCommerce platform. The problem is - it doesn't work. It doesn't display the image sub_field called "photoTest" in the page_sliders.

I downloaded the widget and tried to figure out this but I have no idea where is the problem.. ACF rule is linked with the widget, in the functions there is an absolute path to the custom widget but I think the problem might be with the custom widget itself so here is the code.

```
<?php
class ACF_Custom_Widget extends WP_Widget {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(
            'acf_custom_widget', 
            __('ACF Custom Widget', 'text_domain'), 
            array( 'description' => __( 'A custom ACF widget', 'text_domain' ), 'classname' => 'acf-custom-widget' ) // Args
        );
    }

    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        echo $args['before_widget'];
        if ( !empty($instance['title']) ) {
            echo $args['before_title'] . apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] ). $args['after_title'];
        }
        echo get_field('title', 'widget_' . $args['widget_id']);?>

<?php
    
    if ( is_shop() ){
        $page_id = get_option( 'woocommerce_shop_page_id' ); 
    }
    else {
        $page_id = get_the_ID();
    }

if( have_rows('page_sliders', $page_id) ): ?>

    <div id="carouselControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <?php while( have_rows('page_sliders', $page_id) ): the_row(); 
                // vars
                $image = get_sub_field('photoTest', $page_id);
                ?>
                <div class="photo-wrap">
                <img src="<?php echo esc_url($image['url']); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr($image['alt']); ?>" />
                </div>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>
    </div>

<?php endif; ?>

       <?php
        echo $args['after_widget'];
    }

    public function form( $instance ) {
        if ( isset($instance['title']) ) {
            $title = $instance['title']; 
        }
    ?>
    <p>
      <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title' ); ?></label>
      <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>">
    </p>
    <?php
    }

    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = array();
        $instance['title'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['title'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] ) : '';
        return $instance;
    }
} 
add_action( 'widgets_init', function(){
  register_widget( 'ACF_Custom_Widget' );
});
```

Please help..thank you.

Comment: Note that when inside of a `have_rows` loop, you do not need to use the `$post_id` parameter for any sub field functions, give it a try

Comment: I will thank and let u know!